# Doing KVL on PNP BJT

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, pnp

I'm trying to find the voltage at the emitter and i use the property they give me of the absolute value VBE where in the book its equal to the small AC signal plus the DC VBE ( in this case that small signal is not applied).

The KVL on PNP BJT is Getting me frustrated.

i want to find the voltage at the emitter so i first set my kvl on Q2 to see if its on.

My loop current is opposite the direction of the arrow on the BJT Q1

-VB-VBE-VE=0 ==> VE=-VB-VBE =-1.2V

My loop current is opposite the direction of the arrow on the BJT Q2

-VB-VBE-VE=0 ==> VE=-VB-VBE =-0.7V

on the book the solution says it should be 0.7V for VE. im not sure why

[image]

Comment: What's the addition of the long-tailed pair diagram at the bottom of your question about? The long-tailed pair cannot work if you hold both \$V_\text{BE}\$ values to a magnitude of \$700\:\text{mV}\$. The only way it actually works is because the two values are allowed to be different. So this whole question is a bit confusing for me. I'm not sure what's needed for help.

Answer (score 2):

A long tailed pair like this is usually operated in common-mode, meaning that the base potentials are very close to each other, often less than a millivolt or so different.

This is so that neither one transistor nor the other "dominates", neither being fully switched off or saturated. In common mode, both transistors are operating in their linear regions.

However, in your question, this is not the case. The difference in base potentials is 0.5V, and one of them is definitely completely switched off. The question is which one?

To find out, understand that one of the transistor's base-emitter PN junction is heavily forward biased, and its emitter is "clamped" to being no more than 0.7V higher in potential than its base. At the same time the other transitor's B-E junction has either less than 0.7V bias or is even reversed biased, and its influence on its emitter potential is negligible.

In other words, one of these transistors has "claimed control" of their shared emitter potential. In this case it's Q2, which has the lower of the two base potentials (0V, as compared to +0.5V at Q1's base). The clamping action of its B-E junction is "dragging" its emitter down in voltage as its base voltage drops, its emitter always being 0.7V above its base, and Q1 can do nothing about it. So here, with Q2's base at 0V, its emitter must be 0.7V higher, at 0.7V.

To put it yet another way, outside of the common mode regime, whichever transistor has the lowest base potential will pull the shared emitter potential down, due to its base-emitter PN junction clamping the potential difference across it to at most 0.7V. Consequently, the other transistor's base-emitter potential difference reduces, switching it off.

Anyway, the answer to the question "what is \$v_E\$?" is: \$v_E=v_{B2}+0.7V=0V+0.7V=+0.7V\$

In summary, this is because Q2's base is *significantly* lower in potential than that of Q1, causing the circuit to operate outside the usual common mode regime. Q2's base-emitter junction becomes the deciding factor in the potential of \$v_E\$, which must be 0.7V above Q2's base potential.

Comment: Excellently explained, I really liked your answer's wording

Answer (score 0):

\$V_{BE}\$ indicates the voltage *from* the base *to* the emitter.  On a PNP, it is negative (you can work this out logically, with some thought).  In your equation, you have all the sign conventions correct, *except* that you should be using \$V_{BE} = -0.7\mathrm{V}\$ (note the negative sign).

Comment: If I were given an VEB= 0.7 could i have used -VB-VEB-VE=0 ==> VE=-VB-VEB

Comment: \$V_{EB}\$ would be non-standard, and indicates the voltage *from* the emitter *to* the base.  Your starting equation would have been \$-V_B + V_{EB} - V_E\$ because of the change in direction -- and then it would work.

Comment: I got confused on PNP. i use P as positive N as negative and when i do KVL i say    -VB ( then i go from Base to emitter) and call that 0.7V ( from the previous question) equals the emitter voltage making my equation look like -VB+VBE=VE. how i i know when to pick up .7 volts and when to drop. i look at the arrow for this convention but i'm not sure.